# JNLP API DownloadService loadResource not working from java 7 update 21

Tags: java, jnlp, java-web-start

I have the following code which used to work seamlessly prior to java 7 update 21 :

```
//url = http://somesite.com/mynewlib.jar

if(ds.isResourceCached(url, null))
  ds.removeResource(url, null);
DownloadServiceListener dsl = ds.getDefaultProgressWindow();
s.loadResource(url, null, dsl);
```

Now,jar files seems to be getting downloaded and cached but they are not available for the code.
The code which accesses the newly downloaded code don't seem to be finding the downaloded(cached) jar resources.

Comment: Be sure to check the JNLP using [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/).